# pywinauto: the path doesn't work

Tags: pywinauto

I tried to edit the 7zip URL field (to change folder)

```
dlg.Edit.type_keys(r"C:\Users\x\Desktop\my folder{ENTER}")
```

The given url is written as expected, but I don't find the way to *apply* the new URL (both code above send back the default URL).

Comment: What is not working? It types the whole text but seems no `{ENTER}` after that? Or it just types nothing? Is your app window active when you run this?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov sorry my question was not precise enough. Yes it types correctly the URL. I edited the question: **pywinauto does its work (7zip is the problem)**. But can you just confirm that the code above containing {ENTER} would work to apply text entered in a field?

Comment: Do you mean 7zip File Manager? I see path is applied by Enter manually (version 16.02 x64). Hmm... Will try it on latest 7zip.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov yes that's 7zip File Manager, last version (16.04 x64)

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I finally figured it out: I was testing an URL that contains space in its name "path/my file" so I needed  `with_spaces = True`  I did not noticed in my test that the url was "path/myfile" . Shame to me!

Comment: I let you write the answer if you have the time. Otherwise I will do it.

Comment: Good, please answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

the answer was

```
dlg.Edit.type_keys(r"C:\Users\x\Desktop\my folder{ENTER}", with_spaces = True)
```

The given path contains a space (`my folder`), so it actually wrote: `C:\Users\x\Desktop\myfolder` without the space and press enter. Since the path was not valid, it came back to the default folder.

I did not mention the space in my question so the answer was not obvious.

ps: I did edit the question and the title to focus on the main point.